# Extract longest strings from sublist within list . Python

Tags: python, string, list, search, greatest-n-per-group

so i have a list of sublists and within the sublists, there are strings.

the strings are usually at different lengths, but can be the same length as well.

below is an example of the list

```
sequences = [['aaa'],['aaaa','bb'],[],['aaaaaa','bb','cccccc']]
```

i want to find a way to extract the LONGEST string from each list and if there are two that are equally long, then take both of those strings

```
example_output = [['aaa'],['aaaa'],[],['aaaaaa','cccccc']]
```

usually i would set a threshold in a for-loop where if it was longer than a certain length then append to a list and then after each iteration append that to a list . . . but i don't have a threshold value in this case

**if possible i would like try and avoid using lambda and functions since this will be within another function**

Comment: You cannot do this with regex. Regex is not a tool for comparing separate strings in lists. Why do you want to avoid `itertools` here?

Comment: Does the order of the output lists matter?  Or only that you're retrieving the elements with the longest length?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i wasn't necessarily trying to avoid using itertools but mostly the incorporation of lambda in the expression.

Comment: @g.d.d.c order of the output list is crucial because each one of the sequences is associated with a certain name in another list. that's why i incorporated some empty lists too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the length of the longest string seen so far as the threshold (`maxlen` in the code below):

```
def get_longest(seq):
    maxlen = -1
    ret = []
    for el in seq:
        if len(el) > maxlen:
            ret = [el]
            maxlen = len(el)
        elif len(el) == maxlen:
            ret.append(el)
    return ret

sequences = [['aaa'],['aaaa','bb'],[],['aaaaaa','bb','cccccc']]
example_output = list(map(get_longest, sequences))
print(example_output)
```

This produces:

```
[['aaa'], ['aaaa'], [], ['aaaaaa', 'cccccc']]
```

Comment: this is clean and simple. i'm confused, why is maxlen set to -1 ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: So that even an empty string (length 0) is considered an improvement over the initial state. However, `maxlen = 0` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not the most efficient, but easy to understand.

You can first extract the max lengths (here I'm using a generator expression for that), then extract the strings with those lengths.

```
lengths = ( max(len(s) for s in sublist) if sublist else 0 for sublist in sequences )
[ [ s for s in sublist if len(s) == l ] for l, sublist in zip(lengths, sequences) ]
-> [['aaa'], ['aaaa'], [], ['aaaaaa', 'cccccc']]
```

`itertools.izip` is preferable over `zip` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give my shot with the following (cryptic :)) one liner:

```
example_output = [list(filter(lambda x: len(x)==len(max(sub_lst, key=len)), sub_lst)) for sub_lst in sequences]
```